# PHP: Use post to retrieve 'user inputted data' in pseudocode & is Array("value) => $bool allowed?

Tags: php, pseudocode

Trying to write some PHP pseudocode for a recruitmentposter to hang at my university.

The idea is to make readers walk through a list of requirements in their head and go to the QR code if they think they fit the description.

Unfortunately I have virtually no experience @ PHP and therefore am having some difficulty figuring out the following three things:

1. Do I need to use $post(value of ...) to 'retrieve' their personal information or is simply stating the variable/bool enough?
2. Can I use an array like I did in $skills? Basically I want readers to imagine the following: **skilltype | myskill**
3. Is assigning a bool value for the array entries of $interests correct like this? Here I'd want readers to think: **Interest | personalboolvalue**

It would be no surprise to me if this is complete and utter nonsense but it's what I produced after about an hour and a half of sleep-deprived searching. I'd be ever grateful if anyone could shed some light on the matter.

```
<?php

$skills = array ("PHP" => $level, "HTML5" => $level, "CSS3" => $level, "SQL" => $level);

$interests = array ("iOS" => $bool, "start_up" => $bool, "money" => $bool);

if ($skill[0, 1, 2, 3] == "expert") {
    if ($interests[0, 1] == TRUE && $interests[2] == FALSE) {
        if ($interested && $entrepreneur && $concrete_exp && $willing_to_commit) {
            echo "Please go to /images/qrcode.png";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Maybe you should try another approach to this recruitment poster.

Comment: There are 6 lines of valid PHP code there. The opening tag, closing tag and the empty lines.

Comment: Reading it is easy, writing it is significantly harder. 
There's a reason why I need someone good at PHP ;) I'd write it in c#, but there's no point in writing something in a language you're never going to use for your idea.
I'll need to learn it anyway in the coming year so I might as well try to figure php out some more over the weekend.

Fail. I suck at multitasking.

Comment: Most people will, I know for a fact that I did. :). You opened 8 braces, closed one. If conditions have to be wrapped in parentheses. The indentation isn't very nice :(. It'd be better to put all the conditions in one if statement (seperated by && - the and operator which will only validate if both sides are equal to true). Semicolons are required after every line of code in PHP (lines of code being things like your array definitions, the echo statement etc. Basically just after everything you do. It's the first thing you learn in most tutorials :).) Foreach and == isn't a good combination etc

Comment: @Reanimation thanks for the response. Turns out my sleep deprivation is making me sloppy as hell. I was fairly sure I double checked whether you need to close the bracket after recurring if statements, my conclusion was: no you don't. Thought it was odd but disregarded it. Same with the semicolons. 

I'll encapsulate the if statements in a single statement.

Comment: Quickly redid it as edited in main post. Please let me know if it's still outrageously ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full working solution with nice HTML:

```
<?php
// form submission haldling
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (isset($_POST["skills"]) &&
            isset($_POST["interests"]) &&
            $_POST["skills"] == array("PHP", "HTML", "CSS3", "SQL") &&
            $_POST["interests"] == array("iOS", "start_up")) {
        header("location: /images/qrcode.png");
    } else {
        echo "We are not interested by your profile.";
    }
}

$skills = array("PHP", "HTML", "CSS3", "SQL", "World of Warcraft");
$interests = array("iOS", "start_up", "money");
?>

<form name="poll" action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h2>Skills</h2></legend>
        <?php foreach ($skills as $skill) : ?>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" id="<?php echo $skill ?>" value="<?php echo $skill ?>">
                <label for="<?php echo $skill ?>"><?php echo $skill ?></label>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h2>Interests</h2></legend>
        <?php foreach ($interests as $interest) : ?>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="<?php echo $interest ?>" value="<?php echo $interest ?>">
                <label for="<?php echo $interest ?>"><?php echo $interest ?></label>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'd give you reputation but unfortunately I can't yet.

Comment: I am anwsering question for people that can't vote me up on purpose : i need the unsung badge :)